# Three people share one spirit

Tags: pneumatology

Elisha requested a double portion of Elijah’s spirit.

So Elijah has this spirit
Elisha also has this spirit but somehow in a double portion

> “Now when the sons of the prophets who were at Jericho saw him opposite them, they said, **"The spirit of Elijah rests on Elisha."** And they came to meet him and bowed to the ground before him.”
>   ‭‭2 Kings‬ ‭2:15‬ ‭

And then John the Baptizer is said to be Elijah

> “and if you are willing to accept it, he is Elijah who is to come.”
>   ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭11:14‬ ‭

And

> “and he will go before him **in the spirit and power of Elijah**, to turn the hearts of the fathers to the children, and the disobedient to the wisdom of the just, to make ready for the Lord a people prepared."”
>   ‭‭Luke‬ ‭1:17‬

Who is this spirit that was transferred between three individuals?

I understand that spirits can be transferred and divided

> “Then the Lord came down in the cloud and spoke to him, and took some of the Spirit that was on him and put it on the seventy elders. And as soon as the Spirit rested on them, they prophesied. But they did not continue doing it.”
>   ‭‭Numbers‬ ‭11:25‬

Is this what is happening here?

Comment: To the down voter, I clearly got your attention enough for you to act. What is the objection? Leave the down vote I’m not here for points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elisha requested a double portion of Elijah’s spirit.**

So Elijah has this spirit Elisha also has this spirit but somehow in a double portion

> “Now when the sons of the prophets who were at Jericho saw him
>   opposite them, they said, "The spirit of Elijah rests on Elisha." And
>   they came to meet him and bowed to the ground before him.” ‭‭2 Kings‬
>   ‭2:15‬ ‭

**Moses. "I will take part of the Spirit that is on you, and will put it on them,"**

Because of the mutterings of the Israelites about the manna and not having meat to eat, Moses voiced the feeling that the load was too heavy for him alone. Therefore God directed Moses to gather 70 older men and take them to the tent of meeting.

Numbers 11:16-17  (NET Bible)

> 16  The Lord said to Moses, “Gather to me seventy men of the elders of
>   Israel, whom you know are elders of the people and official over them,
>   and bring them to the tent of meeting; let them take their position
>   there with you. 17 Then I will come down and speak with you there, and
>   I will take part of the Spirit that is on you, and will put it on
>   them, and they will bear some of the burden of the people with you, so
>   that you do not bear it all by yourself.

Jesus began His ministry “in the power of the Spirit.”

Luke 4:14 (NASB)

> " And Jesus returned to Galilee in the power of the Spirit, and news
>   about Him spread through all the surrounding district."

Jesus  told His followers, “You shall receive power when the holy Spirit has come upon you”

Acts 1:8 (NASB)

> "But you will receive power when the Holy Spirit has come upon you;
>   and you shall be My witnesses both in Jerusalem and in all Judea and
>   Samaria, and even to the remotest part of the earth.”

Elizabeth filled with holy Spirit.

Luke 1:41 (NASB)

> 41 When Elizabeth heard Mary’s greeting, the baby leaped in her womb;
>   and Elizabeth was filled with [the] Holy Spirit.

The baptism with holy spirit began at Pentecost 33 C.E.

Matthew 3:11  (NASB)

> 11 “As for me, I baptize you with water for repentance, but He who is
>   coming after me is mightier than I, and I am not fit to remove His
>   sandals; He will baptize you with the Holy Spirit and fire.

How do we understand these expressions? "Jesus started his ministry in the power of the spirit. "(Luke 4:14NASB). "You will receive power when the holy Spirit comes upon you,"(Moffat Acts 1:8) "you will abound in hope by the power of the Holy Spirit."(Romans 15:13  NASB) "Elizabeth was filled with Holy Spirit." (Luke 1:41 NASB)

The scriptures help us.When  the angel Gabriel announced to Mary that she would have a son even though she was a virgin, the angel told her:

James Moffat Luke 1:35

> The angel answered her, "The holy Spirit will come upon you, the power
>   of the Most High will overshadow you; hence what is born will be
>   called holy, Son of God.

According to Gabriel's words, the Bible connects the holy Spirit with  God's divine power. A similar idea appears also in Micah 3:8. Micah said: "**On the other hand I am filled with power, with the Spirit of the Lord. (NASB)**

**Conclusion**

From the foregoing we notice that the holy Spirit can be "distributed", "shared", "spoken of as filling people" they can be ‘baptized’ with it; and they can be “anointed” with it. (Luke 1:41; Matt. 3:11; Acts 10:38).   The Scriptures most often refer to it and connect the holy Spirit as the POWER OF THE MOST HIGH.

Jewish scholars, examining the references to it in the Old Testament Scriptures, have never defined the holy Spirit as anything but the power of God.

In the New Testament, Paul referred to it as the spirit of power, love, and a sound mind:" **For God did not give us a Spirit of fear but of power and love and self-control."(2 Timothy 1:7NET)**